# How to use Faker's unique method with generator objects

Tags: python, faker

I want to use the Faker multi-locale mode (https://maleficefakertest.readthedocs.io/en/docs-housekeeping/fakerclass.html#multiple-locale-mode) and pass a list of locales to my Faker object, then call the respective locale generator and generate unique values when needed in my code.

The "unique" attribute works fine for a Faker object, but does not when it is operating on a Faker Generator. I can see what is happening, but was expecting/hoping that I could just use the same "unique" method with the multi-locales mode. For example:

```
from faker import Faker

fake1 = Faker("en_US")
fake2 = Faker(["en_CA", "en_US"])

print(type(fake1))
print(fake1.state())
print(fake1.unique.state())

print(type(fake2["en_US"]))
print(fake2["en_US"].state())
print(fake2["en_US"].unique.state())
```

Gives:

```
<class 'faker.proxy.Faker'>
Arizona
Illinois
<class 'faker.generator.Generator'>
Oregon
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 12, in <module>
    print(fake2["en_US"].unique.state())
AttributeError: 'Generator' object has no attribute 'unique'
```

Does anyone know a way to use "unique" with the multi-locale mode?

Answer (score 0):

The good news is, Canada has provinces, so you can call `fake2.unique.province()` 13 times (10 provinces, 3 territories) before getting a `UniquenessException`.

The bad news is, in playing around with your problem for another locale that also has states (Australia), I couldn't make much sense of the behaviour. It seems to depart from what you want.

Just from observation, it becomes likely that you start getting `UniquenessException` once one of the locales is exhausted (likely to be Australia in this case, having 8 states).

```
fake3 = Faker(['en_US', 'en_AU'])
for i in range(70):
    try:
        print(fake3.unique.state())
    except:
        print("UniquenessException")
```

```
Iowa
Georgia
Tasmania
Idaho
Alabama
Australian Capital Territory
Maine
Montana
Western Australia
Victoria
Queensland
Kentucky
Pennsylvania
New South Wales
Rhode Island
Arizona
South Australia
Louisiana
Northern Territory
Missouri
UniquenessException
Nevada
UniquenessException
Alaska
Connecticut
UniquenessException
Delaware
Kansas
UniquenessException
Indiana
Texas
UniquenessException
UniquenessException
UniquenessException
New York
UniquenessException
UniquenessException
New Mexico
UniquenessException
UniquenessException
UniquenessException
Illinois
Mississippi
UniquenessException
West Virginia
Ohio
Arkansas
Wyoming
UniquenessException
UniquenessException
New Hampshire
UniquenessException
UniquenessException
Hawaii
UniquenessException
Vermont
UniquenessException
North Dakota
UniquenessException
North Carolina
South Carolina
Washington
UniquenessException
UniquenessException
Minnesota
UniquenessException
Utah
UniquenessException
UniquenessException
Tennessee
```

Comment: Thanks for your response and looking at this too.

Comment: The way you are calling the faker instance is slightly different to the way I called my fake2. I am using the explicit locale name "en_US" to get US data. You are not specifying which locale, and hence you are getting the mix of US and AU states in your for loop. The reason you are getting a random output of US and AU states is because of the way faker randomly selects between valid locales in multi-locale mode

Comment: it seems to me that the unique method/attribute does not work with the generator assigned to the individual faker generator instances for each locale in multi-locale mode

Comment: Ah yes, I was just exploring the behaviour of multi-locale more generally to see if I could tease out any insights that might help with specifying a single locale within a multi.